# Localization Model DataAnnotation in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a multilanguage site running on ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

The data annotation should be based on user language; I can make the site bilingual using `sharedResource` class.

The issue is how to make the model data annotation error bilingual; currently, I only got the data annotation `ErrorMessage`.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
             .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
              //.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();// <--- for ERROR MSG -----
              .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(
                 options => {
                     options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                         factory.Create(typeof(DataAnnotationResource));
                 });// <---------- For ERROR MSG -----
```

FactoryData Model

```
public class FactoryData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "General.RequiresMessageOOO")]
    public string NameInAr { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "General.RequiresMessageOOO")]
    [MaxLength(2, ErrorMessage = "General.MaxlengthExceededOOO")]
    public string NameInEn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1,3)]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `localizationResource` folder:

[image]

The output of this current code

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and I have to do these following changes

from

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(opt =>
    {
        opt.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
    });
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(opts =>
{
    opts.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
        return factory.Create(nameof(SharedResource), assemblyName.Name!);
    };
});
```

Comment: That's great! That's the only way that worked for me too.

Comment: Worked for me out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use resources in DataAnnotations this way :

```csharp
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "General.RequiresMessageOOO", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
[MaxLength(2, ErrorMessageResourceName = "General.MaxlengthExceededOOO", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
public string NameInEn { get; set; }
```

and in your `SharedResource.resx` file :

```xml
<data name="General.RequiresMessageOOO" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This field must not be empty</value>
</data>
<data name="General.MaxlengthExceededOOO" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The value exceeded the max lenght</value>
</data>
```

In my application I have several **SharedResource** files for each language available :

[image: Resources]

You can get more detail about Localization in the Microsoft documentation here :
[Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0)