# How Bind My Resource file's Key to my properties in ASP.NET Core Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, resources, razor-pages

I Add a Resource File to my projects and I write a Service :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using System.Reflection;
namespace NzShop.Services
{
    public class ComponentsResourceService
    {

        private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;
        public ComponentsResourceService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(ComponentsResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
            localizer = factory.Create(nameof(ComponentsResource), assemblyName.Name!);
        }

        public string Get(string key)
        {
            return localizer[key];
        }
        public class ComponentsResource { }
    }
}
```

In Program.cs add:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
     {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("fa"),
        new CultureInfo("tr"),
        new CultureInfo("en-US")
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization()
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ComponentsResourceService>();
```

How Can control Required Field from my ComponentsResource.resx file:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ?????)]
public string Familly { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly bind the resource to `ErrorMessage`.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{ComponentsResource.FamilyRequired}")]
public string Family { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to set a localized error message for the `Required` attribute using the `.resx` file and there are many Stack Overflow and blog posts that cover this topic.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ?????)]
```

### ErrorMessageResourceName/Type validation attributes

A simple, reliable solution that leverages IntelliSense features/validation is to use the combination of the `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` [validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcename?view=net-7.0) along with `nameof` and `typeof`.

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(ComponentsResource.Required),
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ComponentsResource))]
```

- `ComponentsResource` "is the class corresponding to the .resx file where the validation messages are stored".
- The `nameof` [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) provides IntelliSense completion for resources defined in the `.resx` file.
- The `typeof` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) provides validation of the existence of the `ComponentsResource` class.

Applying the above to your property:

```
[BindProperty]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(ComponentsResource.Required),
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ComponentsResource))]
public string? Familly { get; set; }
```

[image]

These attributes are used in these SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699594/how-localize-errormessage-in-dataannotation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71295194/5535143) but answers does not leverage `nameof` while this [blog](https://ziyad.info/en/articles/16-Localizing_DataAnnotations) post does. These posts suggest, however, a common data annotation localization provider configured through the `program.cs` file versus the `ErrorMessageResourceName/ErrorMessageResourceType` validation attributes above.

### IValidationMetadataProvider

This Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518338/5535143) provides a solution where a localized string format for a validation attribute like `[Required]` is configured commonly through `program.cs`.

```
builder.Services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new LocalizedValidationMetadataProvider());
    })
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

where the validation metadata provider is defined as:

```
public class LocalizedValidationMetadataProvider : IValidationMetadataProvider
{
    public LocalizedValidationMetadataProvider()
    {
    }

    public void CreateValidationMetadata(ValidationMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

The SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518338/5535143) provides the full set of steps and code.