Choose proper language for data annotations in ASP.NET
I'm trying to localize error messages for data annotations attributes. I created two resx-files:
DataAnnotationsLocalization.resx
> DataAnnotationsLocalization.Designer.cs
DataAnnotationsLocalization.uk.resx

I'm calling AddDataAnnotationsLocalization in Program.cs and now trying to use it in my page model:
[MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "LocationAddressFormatError")]
public string Address { get; set; }

But as a result of this I see only my English resources shown while for other localized strings I see them according to the current culture (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).
I've put breakpoint into the Designer.cs but it never gets hit. Seems like the framework goes straight to DataAnnotationsLocalization.resx and doesn't consider other languages versions.
How can I show proper language version for the current culture?

check this thread - it might help. NET 6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71294332/localization-model-dataannotation-in-asp-net-core-6-mvc

@PowerMouse my case is different, framework uses my resources but only for English.

Make sure you have set the .resx file to public. you have set the middleware in the startup file. instead of using the ErrorMessage try to use  ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName here is the thread you could refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20699676/11147346.

@JalpaPanchal I searched through SO and tried different neither of these two works for me. Regarding public resources, not sure why I need them public as they are in the same assembly but I've tried this and it didn't change anything.

Appeared that I had wrong Build Action for localized version of the resource file. After I'd changed it to Embedded resource everything started to work as expected.


You should make .resx as public
https://i.imgur.com/zrGqYk4.png
and use your resources like this
[MinLength(10, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LocationAddressFormatError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsLocalization)]
public string Address { get; set; }

